# Redirecionar usuários para aplicativo do Google Maps utilizando Waypoints

Tags: javascript, android, google-maps

Estou montando um site (html/php/javascript/css) com integração com o google Maps usando a API JavaScript.

```
function initMap() {
    var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
    var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer;
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 11,
        center: cidade
    });

    directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
    //Painel texto
    calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay);
    directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById('right-panel'));
}

function calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay) {
  directionsService.route({
    origin: document.getElementById('endOrigem').value,
    destination: document.getElementById('endDest').value,
    waypoints: waypoints,
    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
  }, function(response, status) {
    if (status === google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
    } else {
      window.alert('ERRO!!');
    }
  });
}
```

Até aqui está tudo funcionando perfeitamente. A rota abre em uma div no próprio site.

O que preciso é, quando acessarem o site com Android/iOS essa Rota seja aberta no Maps do usuário, ou pelo menos pergunte ao usuário se ele quer abrir no brownser ou no Maps.

Não sei como passar esses parâmetros (origem, destino e **waypoints**) na url?!

Answer (score 0):

Você deve fazer via Intent

exemplo:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
Uri.parse("https://maps.google.ch/maps?saddr=[address1]&daddr=[address2] to:[address3] to: [address4]"));
startActivity(intent);
```

Troque o [address#] com os waypoints

Comment: Leonardo, isso no android neh? Mas e para redirecionar via html ou java, tem como? do browser chamar o google maps..

Answer (score 0):

Existe duas formas de você fazer isso.

#### Geo

Você pode utilizar a API de geo do Android para isso, passando o endereço ou as coordenadas. Um exemplo de uso seria assim:

```
 <p><a href="google.navigation:q=San+Francisco">Navigation to San Francisco</a></p>
 <p><a href="google.navigation:q=50,10">Navigation to 50/10</a></p>
```

Veja a [documentação oficial](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common.html#Maps)

#### Abrir o endereço do google maps com a busca

Você pode passar o link com o endereço buscado, assim o Android irá sugerir para utilizar um aplicativo de mapas, como o Google Maps.

`http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=street+adress&daddr=street+address`

#### Exemplos de usos

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Geo Link Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p><a href="geo:50,10">Location 50/10</a></p>
        <p><a href="geo:Vienna">Location Vienna</a></p>
        <p><a href="geo:?z=5&q=New+York">Zoom 5, Search for New York</a></p>
        <p><a href="geo:?q=San+Francisco&z=15">Zoom 15, Search for San Francisco</a></p>
        <p><a href="google.navigation:q=San+Francisco">Navigation to San Francisco</a></p>
        <p><a href="google.navigation:q=50,10">Navigation to 50/10</a></p>
        <p><a href="http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=New+York&daddr=San+Francisco">Route New York --> San Francisco</a></p>
        <p><a href="http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=50,10&daddr=50,20">Route 50/10 --> 50/20</a></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Existem algumas coisas que não irão funcionar como o esperado, pois você não está utilizando de forma nativa, mas essa é a melhor forma de fazer o que deseja sem utilizar qualquer outra linguagem/framework.

Para mais detalhes, veja [esta resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23233315/4843158)